# Smooth camera causes zoom factor to change

Tags: android-camera, andengine

I have a game play scene in which the user can zoom in and out, for which I used smooth camera in the following manner:

```
public static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 1024;
public static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 600;
public static final float MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_X = 400f;
public static final float MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_Y = 400f;
public static final float ZOOM_FACTOR_CHANGE = 1f;

mSmoothCamera = new SmoothCamera(0, 0,
                                 Constants.CAMERA_WIDTH,
                                 Constants.CAMERA_HEIGHT,
                                 Constants.MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_X,
                                 Constants.MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_Y,
                                 Constants.ZOOM_FACTOR_CHANGE);
mSmoothCamera.setBounds(0f, 0f,
                        Constants.CAMERA_WIDTH,
                        Constants.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

But the above creates a problem for me. When the user performs zoom-in and leaves game play scene, then other scene behaviours do not look good. I have set zoom factor to 1 to fix this. But now it shows camera translation in other scenes. Because scene switching time it so short, the player can easily see camera translation, which is something I don't want. After the camera repositions, everything works perfect but how do I set camera position properly?

For example, my loading text moves from bottom to top or vice versa, based on camera movement.  Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Please give more detail so that I can help you, or you can use the following method:

```
mSmoothCamera.setMaxVelocity() method and mSmoothCamera.setCenter()
```

And increase your MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_X and MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_Y value, e.g. to more than 800 or 1000. Example:

```
mSmoothCamera.setMaxVelocity(x, y)
```

where x = MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_X and y = MAXIMUM_VELOCITY_Y.

Following is optional:

`mSmoothCamera.setCenter(as_per_your_requirement);`

where as_per_your_requirement means the camera center.

Comment: No this suggestion not work for me. I provide more detail in the following post. http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/smooth-camera-zoom-factor-change-t12730.html

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know if this issue is still valid but I had also this issue, try use mCamera.setZoomFactorDirect(1.0f); in your menu scene constructor.

It`s works for me